# gradle dependency:resolve analog like in maven

Tags: gradle

What analog of Maven:

```
$ mvn dependency:resolve
```

which is:

```
$ mvn help:describe -Dcmd=dependency:resolve
Mojo: 'dependency:resolve'
dependency:resolve
  Description: Goal that resolves the project dependencies from the
    repository.
```

for Gradle?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: resolves the project dependencies from the *remote* Maven/Ivy like repository

Comment: Sure, but *why* do you want to do that? What's the exact use case? The Gradle cache is opaque (unlike the local Maven repo), and will be populated on demand, so you shouldn't need to resolve upfront. If you want to check if your dependency declarations are correct, `gradle dependencies` is your best (out-of-the-box) bet. Or perhaps just run `gradle build` (that's what I usually do).

Comment: Ok, `mvn` have separate command for that (expose it's own modular model), but `gradle` forget about that... With `dependency:resolve` I don't need do `clean` after build. Build of Spring Framework take 5 min, I don't like that, even I just want browse source tree in IDE without *red lines*/errors.

Comment: try `gradle dependencies --refresh-dependencies`

Comment: If the goal is to get latest sources in the IDE, the solution is to regenerate or resync the IDE project (depending on which IDE integration you use), not to resolve manually. Don't understand your `clean` related point.

Comment: Goal to be sure that all packages available for the build. Maven can solve such task by dedicated command. I look for a way to do same in another build tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Eugen:

```
$ gradle --refresh-dependencies
```

Sad that `gradle` in any case want to build project! Seems that this because `gradle`  too dumb (actually it have build instruction instead of project model for multi-module project). Maven is better handle situation in this case.

**PS** To avoid extra steps (like `test`) explicitly state only compilation:

```
$ gradle --refresh-dependencies compileJava
```